# How to use a database in Qgis

Tags: qgis, database

What is the primary use of database in Q-Gis? How to connect to a database in Qgis?

Comment: Which database to you need to connect to?

Comment: Any database like Post Gis,MYsql like that?

Comment: For quick information please check following tutorial :http://getspatial.com/gisblog/qgis-vector-data-connection

Comment: @Sunil: this tutorial is very helpful, thanks for pointing on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your question Please check [this tutorial](http://getspatial.com/gisblog/qgis-vector-data-connection.) this will help you to know how to add/create database connection in QGIS.

**Quick Points :**

Above links covers How to make new DB connection,Add ESRI Personal Geo-database Layers,Add MySQL Spatial Layer etc.

Please go through that and let us know if you have any questions..

**Updated Link :**

Click [here](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/spatialdb/node/1961) to add new postgis connection & view data in QGIS

Comment: Just be aware this isn't how you connect to postgres, mssql, spatialite.

Comment: @Nathan W Thanks for the reply. I have added new link in the answer.